# Where should CF ORM functions relating to multiple instances belong?

Tags: function, orm, model, coldfusion-9, multiple-instances

I want to concatenate the values of two columns into one when retrieving all instances of a model. I am unsure where this function should be located though.

If I place it in the model it can only be called on a specific instance, and it relates to all instances so that isn't correct.

Or is there a better way of retrieving the data? It will be used in a form select box.

```
...
<cfquery name="products" datasource="#########">
    SELECT (brand + ' ' + name) AS [product], id
    FROM products
</cfquery>
...
```

multiple instances as in multiple products in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the scope of this function is "multiple instances" rather than "single instance". If it's simply concatenating values of a single object, then it's a calculated property of that object, even if it's only used when you have more than one of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Dave, I don't understand your references to "instances", but here is what I do with CF ORM if I need two fields concatenated into a commonly used value -- I'd add this function to the definition CFC itself.

```
/**
* products
* @output false
* @persistent true
*/
component
{
    property name="id" fieldtype="id";
    property name="name";
    property name="brand";

    // concatenate fields to make Product 
    public string function getProduct() {
        return variables.brand & " " & variables.name;
    }
}
```

Then after retrieving the entity, call getID() and getProduct() for the 2 fields you use.